# CSS slow response time with Sinatra

Tags: html, css, ruby, sinatra

I have searched high and low and cannot seem to find an answer to my question. I am creating a webpage using Ruby and Sinatra and I have had some issues with my /css/styles.css. I know that my routing is correct because I have styles being applied to my site; however, I have noticed that sometimes (more often than I'd like) the styles do not want to load. I have a form field that I have hidden with:

```
#duration-field {
  display: none;
}
```

This has been working; however, when I remove it and put it back it just doesn't seem to want to load. This is just one example, but many times, styles do not get applied right away. It may take up to 10 minutes or so for the styles to be applied. As I am sure you can imagine, this really slows down the process. I have tried opening the console, going to sources, and refreshing, but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Has anybody experienced this before and know what may be causing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find an answer online. However, I cleared my browser cache and it is now working properly. If anybody knows why this is needed, I'd be happy to know why.